# How to pass context to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to pass activity context to `onReceive` of `MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` class. For that, I pass the context while setting intent:

```
myAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, d.getTime(),   
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1,
    myIntentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
```

However, context in `onReceive` is not the same as one passed in `myAlarmManager`. Why?

Comment: what do u want to achieve from this?

Comment: Nayan Srivastava, thanks for quick reply. I need to pass this context to other method, and there this context is used to create and show _**AlertDialog**._

Comment: ok, makes sense but thats not possible directly. rather open new activity with dialog theme.

Comment: Brian Tompsett, thanks format improving.

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` provided to a `BroadcastReceiver` is not the same as what is used to create the `BroadcastReceiver` or anything you can modify.  It is a limited variant of a `Context` and that is intentional by the framework.  If you have anything significant to do in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you'll need to start your own `Service` or use some other mechanism to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

> and there this context is used to create and show AlertDialog

Triggering a dialog based on an alarm is fairly dangerous to the user. You have no idea what the user is doing at that time, and the dialog may interfere with the user (e.g., you pop up a dialog over their real-time turn-by-turn navigation session). Please use a `Notification`, either all the time or based on a user preference.

Beyond that, you cannot rely on your original `MainActivity` instance to exist anymore at the time the alarm goes off. After all, it should be fairly obvious that if you schedule an alarm to occur a week from now, your original activity instance will have been long since destroyed.

You are welcome to post an event on an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, etc.). That way, if you *do* happen to have UI in the foreground, it can display the dialog. And, if you *don't* happen to have UI in the foreground, you can do something else (e.g., display a `Notification`). I have sample apps that show this [for `LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager) and [for greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot3).

Comment: Thanks for a valuable suggestion. My alarm is supposed to be scheduled  <= 1 day from now, but even though I have no idea about the future fate of my activity. Maybe, it is worth to consider `Notification`.